# How to constrain resizing in blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

When I am scaling two or more vertices, they scale so quickly that I am not able to control properly how much I want to scale. Any way to control this function?

Comment: hold shift while scaling to minimize the effect

Comment: does that solve your problem ?

Comment: No, the effect didn't minimize. It is still the same.

Comment: No. moving is not a problem. Scaling is. The object just becomes REALLY big really quickly.

Comment: If I use the scale button, then the object scales fine. But if I use the scale manipulator, then it scales very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

To minimize the scaling process ( or any transformation ) hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> after pressing <kbd>S</kbd> or after holding the manipulator handle.

When you are trying to make the object smaller make sure to place your mouse cursor as far as possible to have a space to move it inward ( and vice versa ), this may be problem with manipulator as it is relatively small and don't leave much room for movement inward for this you can try resizing the manipulator from **User_Preferences**➩**Interface**➩**Manipulator**➩**Size** :

[image]